# searching for a value in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arrayobject

i have a small problem here..

```
for(int i=0; i<employee.length-1;i++){

            if(employee[i].getID()==ID){
                System.out.println("Employee Record for "+employee[i].getfName()+" "+employee[i].getlName()+" (ID#"+employee[i].getID()+"):\n"
                        + "Basic Pay: "+employee[i].getSalary(0)+"\n"
                        + "Housing Allowence: "+employee[i].getSalary(1)+"\n"
                        + "Travel Allowence:  "+employee[i].getSalary(2)+"\n"
                        + "Net Salary : "+employee[i].getNetSalary()+"\n"
                        + "Taxable : "+employee[i].getTaxable());break;}


       if(i==employee.length-1){
           System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NOT FOUND !!!");}
```

this is my code to search for an employee by his id .. i get an error message when i run!
 the values are entered by the user and i don't have a problem with that

the error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dd1318398p2.EmpRecord.searchEmpID(EmpRecord.java:103)
    at dd1318398p2.EmpRecord.main(EmpRecord.java:37)
Java Result: 1
```

the error is referring to the first if statement

Comment: can you at least also include the error you are receiving?

Comment: that quite obviously means that `employee[i]` is `null`.

Comment: I hope your code doesn't look like that.  Your `break` statement looks like someone who's blending into a crowd because he doesn't want his ex-wife to see him.  It's kind of an important part of your logic, so why would you want to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error refers to the first `if` statement,

```
if(employee[i].getID()==ID)
```

And that gives you a NullPointerException then `employee[i]` must be null. You can check for that like,

```
if (employee[i] != null && employee[i].getID()==ID)
```

Or, if you need a bunch of if tests use a continue...

```
if (employee[i] == null) continue;
if(employee[i].getID()==ID) {
}
```

Comment: thank you ,it worked but i dont understand the problem ! can you explain it please ?

Comment: `employee[i]` was null. Null does not have an ID to get, because null is synonymous with "not a value".